# Linked list operation on nodes (floyd cycle detection)

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

#### Structure

```cpp
SinglyLinkedListNode {
      int data;
      SinglyLinkedListNode* next;
 };
```

#### Function

```cpp
bool has_cycle(SinglyLinkedListNode* head) {
    SinglyLinkedListNode* s=head,*f=head->next;
    while(s != NULL && f != NULL && f->next != NULL)
    {
        s = s->next;
        f = f->next->next;
        if(s->data == f->data)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

According to the algorithm, if the slow pointer `s` and fast pointer `f` arrive on the same node the list is said to have a cycle. I'm assuming the same node will have the same data but then why am I getting failed test cases?

When I change `(s->data = f->data)` to `(s == f)` it works fine.
**What is the difference between `s == f` and `s->data == f->data`?**

Comment: `s==f` is comparing pointers and `s->data==f->data` is comparing (part of) what are pointed at. Would you mind posting a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The same node will have the same data, but nodes having the same data need not be same.

Comment: You say you change `(s->data = f->data)`, but your code have `(s->data == f->data)` instead of that. Which one is what you are actually using?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is your final checking condition. This will fail in a test case where there can be duplicates present (in the loop). When you are checking for the "same node" checking if the pointer value is same is better because it will always be unique, i.e., every node has an unique address but it is not necessary for it to be true for the value the node contains. For example:

1 -> 3 ->4 ->5 -> 6 -> 4 -> 7 -> NULL

//Note giving relative indexing(0th, 1st, .. and random addressing for understanding)

Iter 1: s is at 1(0th node, 1000010092) while f is at 3(1st node, 21983193)

Iter 2: s is at 3(1st node, 21983193) while f is at 5(3rd node, 129764714)

Iter 3: s is at 4(2nd node, 12984124) while f is at 4(5th node, 149284124)

See the ambiguity!!

Even though your algorithm is giving a TRUE a cycle doesn't exist.
But if you checked by the addressing, this false positive wouldn't have happened.
Tip: check if there are duplicates in any problem, they tend to be added to bring up such issues.